# Reading String as buffer for SerialPort using Start and Stop characters with C#

Tags: c#, buffer

The serial protocol i'm interfacing with uses start and stop characters to define the "packet", sometimes it triggers the event handler all together, sometimes in two dumps.  Regardless I believe some form of confirmation is required to build a more robust application.  I am very new so I appreciate your patience but as much reading as I have done on MSDN I can't seem to find an optimum way to do this.  I appreciate in advance any guidance you may provide.

```
    private void ComPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {           
            // Read all the data waiting in the buffer
            string buffer = ComPort.ReadExisting();
            // Process String for Start "//" and Stop "\\" Characters

            //Remove data from buffer and send to seperate routine for processing               

    }
```

Comment: This is entirely normal, you get what is "existing".  Which is usually just a few characters, serial ports are slow.  You must append what you received to a buffer and not process it until you got the last character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the received data to a `StringBuilder` instance that is a field of the class containing your DataReceived method. Such you can "collect" pieces of the packet. Each time you receive some data, you check whether the `StringBuilder` contains your start/stop characters. Only then you extract the message. Afterwards you would delete that package (including start/stop) from the `StringBuilder`. Now check again if it contains another package (more start/stop), because as well as receiving packages in parts it is possible that you get more than one package at a time.

Comment: I have been successful at appending data to a stringbuilder instance however now as I look for ways to search and manipulate it I am reading that stringbuilder does not provide effective search capabilities and I should be using string.

Comment: StringBuilder is very effective in appending. You can get a String from it via .ToString() or use a char[] for searching from .CopyTo.

Comment: Still working on it, but your reiteration of stringbuilder's abilities forced me to look closer and its doing what I need it to do, and it would seem to do it faster.